# Mount filesystem through network, works with file explorer, can't figure it out mount

Tags: linux, filesystems, arch-linux, samba, raspbian

I have connected a USB drive to my internet box in order to share it on my network. I am trying to mount it automatically on boot on two of my linux computers running Archlinux and Raspbian.

On both of these, the file explorer is able to mount the network device. Both explorers (the default ones in Arch/Mate and in Raspbian) can find it and prompt me for credentials, where I select Anonymous access. I am not sure how they proceed, and I don't know how to mount it in the folder I want nor how to have it mounted at boot.

In Raspbian, it seems to be mounted at `/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=livebox\,share\=usb_130`, but I can't get past`/run/user/1000/gvfs` when I try to access it on arch.

smb utilities find my disk

```
(both)# smbtree -N
WORKGROUP
    \\LIVEBOX               Livebox
        \\LIVEBOX\usb_130           Additional storage
        \\LIVEBOX\IPC$              IPC Service (Livebox)
```

But I can't mount it in ways I am used to, both systems give me different errors.

```
(arch)[root@lu-tze ~]# mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.1/usb_130 /mnt
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //192.168.1.1/usb_130 /mnt
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Also tried other things instead of the ip (livebox, workgroup/livebox, without usb_130, etc.)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t cifs -o guest //LIVEBOX/usb_130/ /mnt
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Note that this IP pings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess is that your NAS only supports SMBv1 (CIFS) while new kernels always try to use SMBv2/3 (the modern versions). To use SMBv1 again, mount with the **`vers=1.0`** option.

```
mount -t cifs -o guest,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1 /mnt
```

My second guess is that it's hostname-related:

- The hostname `LIVEBOX` is probably only available through NetBIOS (NBNS) – your NAS doesn't register itself properly with local DNS (or there is no local DNS).
- GNOME software use a *libsmbclient*-based client, which can resolve NetBIOS names on its own, but `mount -t cifs` relies on there being system-wide support for NBNS, i.e. /etc/nsswitch.conf must have `wins` listed as one of the "hosts:" modules, and the `nmbd` service must be running.
- As an alternative, you could add `192.168.1.1 livebox` to your /etc/hosts, which might be the most reliable method since the device's IP address seems unlikely to change.
- Finally, connecting directly to `192.168.1.1` should work with most SMB servers, but if your NAS doesn't accept this for some odd reason (related to its SMBv1 usage), you can try mounting with the `servernetbiosname=` option:

  ```
  mount -t cifs -o guest,vers=1.0,servernetbiosname=LIVEBOX //192.168.1.1 /mnt
  ```

Comment: Your first thought was enough, `vers=1.0` works, thank you.